# Any good idea for OpenCL atom_inc separation?

Tags: opencv, sum, opencl

I want to  count the total non-zero points number in an image using OpenCL.

Since it is an adding work, I used the atom_inc.

And the kernel code is shown here.

```
__kernel void points_count(__global unsigned char* image_data, __global int* total_number, __global int image_width)
{
    size_t gidx = get_global_id(0);
    size_t gidy = get_global_id(1);
    if(0!=*(image_data+gidy*image_width+gidx))
    {
        atom_inc(total_number);
    }
}
```

My question is, by using atom_inc it will be much redundant right?

Whenever we meet a non-zero point, we should wait for the atom_inc.

I have a idea like this, we can separate the whole row into hundreds groups, we find the number in different groups and add them at last.

If we can do something like this:

```
 __kernel void points_count(__global unsigned char* image_data, __global int* total_number_array, __global int image_width)
{
    size_t gidx = get_global_id(0);
    size_t gidy = get_global_id(1);
    if(0!=*(image_data+gidy*image_width+gidx))
    {
        int stepy=gidy%10;
        atom_inc(total_number_array+stepy);
    }    
}
```

We will separate the whole problem into more groups.
In that case, we can add the numbers in the total_number_array one by one.

Theoretically speaking, it will have a great performance improvement right?

So, does anyone have some advice about the summing issue here?

Thanks!

Comment: Reduction problem. Explained thousands of times. Atomic_inc() is not efficient, you need to do it in the O(log2()) mode.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments this is a reduction problem.

The idea is to keep separate counts and then put them back together at the end.

Consider using local memory to store the values.

1. Declare a local buffer to be used by each work group.
2. Keep track of the number of occurrences in this buffer by using the local_id as the index.
3. Sum these values at the end of execution.

Answer (score 1):

A very good introduction to the reduction problem using Opencl is shown here:
http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/opencl-optimization-case-study-simple-reductions/

The reduction kernel could look like this (taken from the link above):

```
__kernel
void reduce(
            __global float* buffer,
            __local float* scratch,
            __const int length,
            __global float* result) {

  int global_index = get_global_id(0);
  int local_index = get_local_id(0);
  // Load data into local memory
  if (global_index < length) {
    scratch[local_index] = buffer[global_index];
  } else {
    // Infinity is the identity element for the min operation
    scratch[local_index] = INFINITY;
  }
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
  for(int offset = get_local_size(0) / 2;
      offset > 0;
      offset >>= 1) {
    if (local_index < offset) {
      float other = scratch[local_index + offset];
      float mine = scratch[local_index];
      scratch[local_index] = (mine < other) ? mine : other;
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
  }
  if (local_index == 0) {
    result[get_group_id(0)] = scratch[0];
  }
}
```

For further explanation see the proposed link.